# Django Postman implementation for sending messages

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-messages

I am trying to use the `Django-Postman` framework to send messages between users in `Django 2.0`.
I have installed the app and made the necessary changes as mentioned [in the docs of the framework](http://django-postman.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).

However when i try to go the the message urls I get a blank page (like this screenshot):

[image: blank page]

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Installed `django-postman`
2. In `settings.py`

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
       'postman',
       'account',
       'cart',
       'shop',
       'landingpage',
   ]
   POSTMAN_I18N_URLS = True  # default is False
   POSTMAN_DISALLOW_ANONYMOUS = True  # default is False
   POSTMAN_DISALLOW_MULTIRECIPIENTS = True  # default is False
   POSTMAN_DISALLOW_COPIES_ON_REPLY = True  # default is False
   POSTMAN_DISABLE_USER_EMAILING = True  # default is False
   POSTMAN_FROM_EMAIL = 'from@host.tld'  # default is DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
   POSTMAN_AUTO_MODERATE_AS = True  # default is None
   POSTMAN_SHOW_USER_AS = 'get_full_name'  # default is None
   POSTMAN_NAME_USER_AS = 'last_name'  # default is None
   POSTMAN_QUICKREPLY_QUOTE_BODY = True  # default is False
   POSTMAN_NOTIFIER_APP = None  # default is 'notification'
   POSTMAN_MAILER_APP = None  # default is 'mailer'
   ```
3. And I have linked urls this way in `urls.py`

   ```
   url(r'^messages/', include('postman.urls', namespace='postman')),
   ```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: And what behaviour do you desire, can you be more specific? Have you debugged your code?

Comment: I am trying to create a simple user to user messaging feature in my project.  link to my repo https://github.com/Riwajchalise/proj-django

Comment: Do you have `DEBUG=True` in your settings.py?

Comment: yes DEBUG =TRUE

Answer (score 2):

Try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/postman/message/` if you're on localhost. It should resolve the issue.[image: screenshot of the app url]

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a email backend missing. For example, I added:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
POSTMAN_AUTO_MODERATE_AS = True  # default is None
```